# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Item must exist, When loading CSV's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, csv

When I try to run my rake task `rake import:master`

I am getting this error: 
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Item must exist`

When I try to run the individual rake task: `rake import:item`, I will go into rails console and it will display no items loaded. Does anyone know what might be going wrong? I have spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my rake file:

```
require 'csv'
namespace :import do 
  desc "Imports all CSV's"
  task :master => :environment do 
    Rake::Task["import:customer"].execute
    Rake::Task["import:merchant"].execute
    Rake::Task["import:item"].execute
    Rake::Task["import:invoice"].execute
    Rake::Task["import:transaction"].execute
    Rake::Task["import:invoice_item"].execute
  end 
end 

namespace :import do 
desc "imports merchants from a csv file"
task :merchant => :environment do 
    CSV.foreach("lib/seeds/merchants.csv") do |row|
    id = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    created_at = row[2]
    updated_at = row[3]
    Merchant.create(id: id, name: name, created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at)
    end 
  end 
end 

namespace :import do 
  desc "imports items from a csv file"
  task :item => :environment do 
      CSV.foreach("lib/seeds/items.csv") do |row|
      id = row[0]
      name = row[1]
      description = row[2]
      unit_price = row[3]
      merchant_id = row[4]
      created_at = row[5]
      updated_at = row[6]
      Item.create(id: id, name: name, unit_price: unit_price, merchant_id: merchant_id, created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at)
    end 
  end
end 

namespace :import do 
  desc "imports customers from a csv file"
  task :customer => :environment do
      CSV.foreach("lib/seeds/customers.csv") do |row|
      id = row[0]
      first_name = row[1]
      last_name = row[2]
      created_at = row[3]
      updated_at = row[4]
      Customer.create(id: id, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at)
    end 
  end 
end 

namespace :import do 
  desc "imports invoices from a csv file"
  task :invoice => :environment do 
      CSV.foreach("lib/seeds/invoices.csv") do |row|
      id = row[0]
      customer_id = row[1]
      merchant_id = row[2]
      status = row[3]
      created_at = row[4]
      updated_at = row[5]
      Invoice.create(id: id, customer_id: customer_id, merchant_id: merchant_id, status: status, created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at)
    end 
  end 
end 

namespace :import do 
  desc "imports invoice_items from a csv file"
  task :invoice_item => :environment do 
      CSV.foreach("lib/seeds/invoice_items.csv") do |row|
      id = row[0]
      item_id = row[1]
      invoice_id = row[2]
      quantity = row[3]
      unit_price = row[4]
      created_at = row[5]
      updated_at = row[6]
      InvoiceItem.create!(id: id, item_id: item_id, invoice_id: invoice_id, quantity: quantity, unit_price: unit_price, created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at)
    end
  end 
end 

namespace :import do 
  desc "imports transactions from a csv file"
  task :transaction => :environment do 
      CSV.foreach("lib/seeds/transactions.csv") do |row|
      id = row[0]
      invoice_id = row[1]
      credit_card_number = row[2]
      credit_card_expiration_date = row[3]
      result = row[4]
      created_at = row[5]
      updated_at = row[6]
    Transaction.create(id: id, invoice_id: invoice_id, credit_card_number: credit_card_number, credit_card_expiration_date: credit_card_expiration_date, result: result, created_at: created_at, updated_at: updated_at)
    end 
  end 
end
```

Here is also my schema if that helps

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_11_27_030804) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "invoice_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.bigint "invoice_id"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.decimal "unit_price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["invoice_id"], name: "index_invoice_items_on_invoice_id"
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_invoice_items_on_item_id"
  end

  create_table "invoices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "customer_id"
    t.bigint "merchant_id"
    t.string "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_customer_id"
    t.index ["merchant_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_merchant_id"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "unit_price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "merchant_id"
    t.index ["merchant_id"], name: "index_items_on_merchant_id"
  end

  create_table "merchants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "invoice_id"
    t.bigint "credit_card_number"
    t.date "credit_card_expiration_date"
    t.string "result"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["invoice_id"], name: "index_transactions_on_invoice_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "invoice_items", "invoices"
  add_foreign_key "invoice_items", "items"
  add_foreign_key "invoices", "customers"
  add_foreign_key "invoices", "merchants"
  add_foreign_key "items", "merchants"
  add_foreign_key "transactions", "invoices"
end
```

And my Item model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :merchant
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_items
  validates_presence_of :name, :description, :unit_price
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: possible issue may be while you creating `InvoiceItem` you reference item as foreign key in invoice_items  table which actually not exists in item table. you need to check your invoice items csv file.

Comment: Does app/models/invoice_item.rb have a `belongs_to :item` line? If so you need to make sure the `item_id` you're using in the `InvoiceItem.create!` line matches an Item id that already exists in the database. Make sure the values you have in row[1] of "lib/seeds/invoice_items.csv" match up with what you have in row[0] of "lib/seeds/items.csv". Failing that you might need to run the two import steps in separate transactions so that the Item creation is committed before the InvoiceItems are

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify what is the item id throwing error while trying to import invoice items from lib/seeds/invoice_items.csv ? You can put some logging there and verify whether that particular item id already exists in item table. If its not there, then its either missing from the items.csv file or it was not inserted during the item import task.

So basically the task you have written got the serious problem related to inconsistent data. We should always try to prevent this by adding proper logging and apply roll back if necessary and catch the exceptions. Also the looping in CSV is not a best practise as it may take some more time when the records in CSV gets huge. So try to make a hash from all the records and keep it in memory, do the validations and start the import after that. Each task will import the data one by one which will trigger the insert query for each and every object. Try to create a batch of records , say 1000 and do a bulk insert so the number of queries are less and import works much faster.